how do I access Pass files when logged into my user's shell from another user's session?
I just migrated from keepassxc to the linux pass password utility. But I often find myself su'ing to my user's account from another user's session, and when I try to run any pass commands on entries in my store, I get a "no secret key" error, which seems odd to me because I would think when one logs into their shell account that everything associated with that user would be available at the cli.
So how then can I su into my user's account from another's user's session in a way that I can access my gpg keys and manage my pass files?

The problem is probably $HOME.  su username doesn't change environment variables.  su - username acts like a completely new login including  environment variables, running your login scripts, and changing your directory.
